# Beacon background searching when app is in inactive status in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon

**What I Did**:- Hi,I have tried to search beacon in background when the app is in inactive state and I also referred a link "**nraboy/ng-cordova-beacon#4**".

Below code **startMonitoringForRegion** doesn't call the "**didEnterRegion**" and "**didExitRegion**".

please help me how to do background search or monitoring

**My code snippet**:-

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBeacon) {
            console.log("start")
            console.log($cordovaBeacon)

    $scope.beacons = {};

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $cordovaBeacon.requestAlwaysAuthorization();

        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didEnterRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {

            var uniqueBeaconKey;
            for(var i = 0; i < pluginResult.beacons.length; i++) {
                uniqueBeaconKey = pluginResult.beacons[i].uuid + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].major + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].minor;
                $scope.beacons[uniqueBeaconKey] = pluginResult.beacons[i];
                       console.log("ibeacon elements")
                       console.log(pluginResult.beacons)
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });

         $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didExitRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
        console.log("ibeacondidExitRegion")
     // $cordovaVibration.vibrate(500);
            });
        $cordovaBeacon.startMonitoringForRegion($cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion("estimote", "uuid"));

       // 
    });
});
```

**For Foreground Its working:-**

**My code snippet**:-

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBeacon) {

    $scope.beacons = {};

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $cordovaBeacon.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBeacon:didRangeBeaconsInRegion", function(event, pluginResult) {
            var uniqueBeaconKey;
            for(var i = 0; i < pluginResult.beacons.length; i++) {
                uniqueBeaconKey = pluginResult.beacons[i].uuid + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].major + ":" + pluginResult.beacons[i].minor;
                $scope.beacons[uniqueBeaconKey] = pluginResult.beacons[i];
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        $cordovaBeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion($cordovaBeacon.createBeaconRegion("estimote", "8A458198-34AE-11E6-AC61-9E71128CAE77"));

    });
});
```

**I was just changed "startRangingBeaconsInRegion" to "startMonitoringForRegion"**

Comment: Does it work with the app in the foreground?

Comment: Yes It's working..I have attached the foreground snippet.Please tell me how to walk up my app in background by notification if any beacon is nearer to a region